# Recommend Web framework for Clojure

Tags: clojure

My next big hobby hack coming up is to make a website for myself with Clojure.  I figure this would be a good way to learn Clojure but trying to plan ahead I think a came across some outdated information.

Right now [Noir](http://webnoir.org/) looks like a winner.  I'm open to any suggestions on what I should try using.

Comment: noir or compojure+hiccup, which is what noir is built on top of.

Comment: shame, the website now says "Noir has been deprecated" :( any other option?

Answer (score 7):

Compojure is a common first choice.

It is very well documented and examples abound.
Because Compojure has been around for a while (in Clojure terms that is) there are some dated tutorials. You can spot these because they will have something like clojure 1.2 in the examples.

Comment: Thanks, one of the reason Noir looks appealing because it built on top of Hiccup, Ring and Compojure but right now I'm not too familiar with any of these libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I have used Noir several times. Highly recommended if you're building a website in Clojure. After a while though, we ended up transferring the majority of the business logic to the client, using Ember.js. Then the Noir Clojure piece became a RESTful json service. The amount of Clojure decreased (I was upset, boo) but the app is much better off this way. Ember is great for building many dependent and connected views which need to sync together when new data is retrieved or persisted.

But I digress.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start looking into Ember.js

Answer (score 3):

It depends on concrete tasks that you want to be solved by Web Framework. 
I think this topic - [Mature Clojure web frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551805/mature-clojure-web-frameworks) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another one that I've been keeping my eye on is [joodo](http://www.joodoweb.com/).